# Send data in email but email data is empty

Tags: email, email-templates

Email code:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $templateId =     Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ATTACHMENTS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE);

        $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($templateId);

        $vars = array('data' => "hello");
        $a = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($vars);
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject("Email");
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($email, $storeId);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderName("AAA", $storeId);
        $emailTemplate->send($email,"AAA", $vars);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading template using template id than you need to use below code:

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($emailTemplateId);
```

Also please check that your template is loading or not:

If its not loading try to loading it by passing it static value as tempalte id

Also check that you are using "data" in template file:

Comment: not working....

Comment: template is loading n  i m using data in template file like this {{var data}} n using static value still email is empty

Comment: The static content of template coming or not?

Comment: its not coming a static content of template

Comment: please check that you have created the html of template on below path:
app/locale/[your_locale_or_en_US]/template/email/[email_template_filename].html

Comment: html file is also created

Comment: Check that you have define that template in config.xml of your module and also created custom template for it in transaction emails.

Comment: yes i m define that in xml